# Can't change TabStrip Styles

Tags: html, css, angular, nativescript

I am new with NativeScript and not the best in CSS and HTML, so my question is on how to change the selected Colors in a NativeScript/Angular project. Properties like selectedItemColor or highlightColor does not appear to exist, when I add them to my CSS script and I also tried
 as you see in the following html script

```css
.home-panel{
    vertical-align: center; 
    font-size: 20;
    margin: 15;
}

.description-label{
    margin-bottom: 15;
}

Button{
    background-color: #4587AD;
    width: 46%;
    margin: 2%;
    height: 95px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-top: 55px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.bottomstrip{
    background: #1D3EB8;
    width: 99%;
    height: 8%;
}

.topNavStrip{
    font-weight: 800;
    background: #1D3EB8;
/* selected-item-color: brown;         does not exist */
}


Tabs{
    margin-top: 4%;
}

SearchBar{
    width: 100%;
}

.t-12{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
    font-size: large;
}

ListView{
    background-color: #6F9DE1;
    border-radius: 35px;
    margin: 30px;
}

.groupPictureRigth{
    height: auto;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 13%;
}

.groupPictureLeft{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<Tabs highlight-color="white">
    <TabStrip class="topNavStrip">
        <TabStripItem>
            <Label text="Find">></Label>
        </TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem>
            <Label text="2">></Label>
        </TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem>
            <Label text="Do">></Label>
        </TabStripItem>
    </TabStrip>
    <TabContentItem>
        <StackLayout>
            <SearchBar hint="Search Community you are in"
                [text]="searchPhrase" (submit)="onSearchSubmit($event)">
            </SearchBar>
        </StackLayout>
    </TabContentItem>
    <TabContentItem>
        <StackLayout>
            <BottomNavigation>
                <TabStrip class="bottomstrip">
                    <TabStripItem>
                        <Image src="~/app/images/account.png">></Image>
                    </TabStripItem>
                    <TabStripItem>
                        <Image src="~/app/images/search_accounts.png"></Image>
                    </TabStripItem>
                    <TabStripItem>
                        <Image src="~/app/images/chat.png"></Image>
                    </TabStripItem>
                    <TabStripItem>
                        <Image src="~/app/images/picture.png"></Image>
                    </TabStripItem>
                    <TabStripItem>
                        <Image src="~/app/images/Gruppe 572.png"></Image>
                    </TabStripItem>
                </TabStrip>
                <TabContentItem>
                        <ns-profile></ns-profile>
                </TabContentItem>
                <TabContentItem>
                    <GridLayout>
                        <Label text="Friends">
                        </Label>
                    </GridLayout>
                </TabContentItem>
                <TabContentItem>
                    <WrapLayout>
                        <Button text="Edit" (tap)="onButtonTap()">
                        </Button>
                        <Button text="New Group/Chat"
                            (tap)="onButtonTapNewGroup()"></Button>
                        <android>
                            <SearchBar hint="Search" [text]="searchPhrase"
                                (submit)="onSearchSubmit($event)">
                            </SearchBar>
                        </android>                        
                        <ListView [items]="groups"
                            (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)">
                            <ng-template let-group="item">
                                <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row">
                                    <Image src="~/app/images/Ellipse.png"
                                        class="groupPictureLeft"></Image>
                                    <Label [text]="group.name"
                                        class="t-12"
                                        verticalAlignment="center">
                                    </Label>
                                    <Image src="~/app/images/tennis.png"
                                        class="groupPictureRigth"></Image>
                                </FlexboxLayout>
                            </ng-template>
                        </ListView>
                    </WrapLayout>
                </TabContentItem>
                <TabContentItem>
                    <GridLayout>
                        <Label text="Picture" class="h2 text-center">
                        </Label>
                    </GridLayout>
                </TabContentItem>
                <TabContentItem>
                    <GridLayout>
                        <Label text="Trophies" class="h2 text-center">
                        </Label>
                    </GridLayout>
                </TabContentItem>
            </BottomNavigation>
        </StackLayout>
    </TabContentItem>
    <TabContentItem>
        <GridLayout>
            <Label text="Do" class="h2 text-center">
            </Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </TabContentItem>
</Tabs>
```